# Android Play gif animation from URL

Tags: android, gif

Somebody, i want play animation from url, i can get InputStream but i dont know how play animation?
Found the code, but there was a small size of the animation. Maybe someone has a good solution?

Try this solution: https://code.google.com/p/android-gifview/source/browse/trunk/GifPlayer/src/jp/tomorrowkey/android/gifplayer/GifDecoder.java
But not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GifAnimatedDrawable](https://github.com/Hipmob/gifanimateddrawable). It looks like it takes an Input stream and converts it to an `AnimationDrawable` so you can use it in an `ImageView`